# Why do iluminating LEDs flicker?

Tags: led

I recently got a [Milwaukee compact floodlight](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071YNVS15), which is a powerful LED hand light.

The light from the device appears constant, but if a scene illuminated by the light is viewed with a scanning imager, it can be seen that the light is actually flickering too fast for the eye to see. Why would this be?

Comment: This is called PWM, and it's the easiest way to adjust the brightness of LEDs--as other methods require controlled current sources, which are not exactly _difficult_ but certainly nontrivial.

Comment: PS I have the M18 floodlight.  Good worklights, but GORSH are they ever bigger than they need to be!

Answer (score 1):

Because they are built down to a price. Reducing flicker costs money.

Because a large part of the population don't notice the flicker, and buy products based on price, not performance. There are no standards AFAIK anywhere in world requiring manufacturers to label products with how much they flicker.

The mains delivers very little energy around the zero crossings when the voltage is low. If you want a LED to emit a steady light, then you need to store energy when the mains voltage is high, and release it to the LED when the input voltage is low. This requires an extra component, called a capacitor. You can save a few pence by leaving it out.

If you omit the energy storage capacitor, then the LED goes dark 100 or 120 times per second when the mains voltage is around the zero crossings.

I unfortunately have very fast eyes. I rejoiced once CRTs were replaced by LCDs, only to weep again as I realised that almost all LED light manufacturers were cheap, and produced stuff that flickered. I am now building a little portable 20W mains-waveform inverter, so I can power-up lights in the shop before I buy. Some brands are better than others. Exterior floodlights seem to be the worst.

Comment: The other factor that may seem obvious is that LEDs are fast. When current falls to zero (even for tiny fractions of a second at zero-crossing), so does the light.

Comment: @glen_geek That *is* the factor. However, a capacitor in the lamp can keep power going to the LED continuously.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs have a threshold voltage below which they do not conduct much current/function usefully.  When they are operated below a certain brightness threshold, they must be dimmed by PWM(Pulse width modulation) so they are on some of the time and off some of the time, and the average of light over that time period is what you see.

An ideal LED driver would use constant voltage/current at any current above the optimal current and PWM dimming below that.  There are minimum frequencies to fool the human eye under different conditions.  200 hz is considered adequate for most lighting, but when fast moving objects are involved, higher frequencies are necessary.  So far as I know at the current time few drivers do this and literature is almost never available indicating which do.

Comment: Normally the LED manufacture defines the best pulse rate for a given LED. Small LEDs <1 Watt can be pulsed at 1 KHZ, while huge 10mm LEDs are pulsed at 500 HZ. Tiny IR LEDs can be pulsed at MHZ frequencies.